# Does the Cursed Scythe's buff not work with the Zweihander?

Tags: lost-ruins

I got the Cursed Scythe and am testing with the Yuki-Onna.

> Effect stacks up to 4 times with each successful attack
>
> Damage +60%
>
> Attack Speed: +1
>
> Enemy's attack power: +40%

No matter how many Cursed Scythe hits are dealt beforehand, each giving me the buff's symbol of a scythe in my status, the Zweihander always deals 14 damage? There's no damage increase from the Cursed Scythe hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursed scythe appears to only buff itself, and not any other weapons.

Comment: Yeah, that seems right. I just didn't notice. I guess I swapped around my loadout so much that I thought my Rune damage increase from the Mage Orb was actually from the Scythe buff.